# Как правильно писать окончание в словах?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать?

> Начало трассы соответствует пикету проектируемому проезду.

или

> Начало трассы соответствует пикету проектируемого проезда.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что предложение должно быть таким.
**Начало трассы обозначено** (или отмечено) **пикетом проектируемого проезда.**

Или таким.
**Началу трассы соответствует пикет проектируемого проезда.**

Пикет (чего? Р. п.) проезда (какого?) проектируемого.

Из энциклопедического словаря:
**пикет** (от франц. *piquet* — кол) (*геод.*) — точка на местности (обозначенная колышком), служащая ориентиром для установки рейки при нивелировании и для закрепления трассы на местности.

**Для сведения** (из технологии строительства автодороги).
Металлической лентой производится разбивка пикетов, которые закрепляются деревянными кольями на расстоянии, равном половине ширины дороги плюс 1 м. Рядом с ними устанавливаются вешки-сторожки. Производится нивелирование вертикальных отметок на каждом пикете, на сторожке указывается глубина выемки или высота насыпки...
(Обычно началу трассы соответствует ПК0 — нулевой пикет.)